# How to construct a chamfered dodecahedron with equilateral or coplanar faces?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, 3d, polyhedra

According to [wikipedia](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3991193/748561), "The chamfered dodecahedron is a convex polyhedron with 80 vertices, 120 edges, and 42 faces: 30 hexagons and 12 pentagons. It is constructed as a chamfer (geometry) (edge-truncation) of a regular dodecahedron. **The pentagons are reduced in size** and **new hexagonal faces are added in place of all the original edges**." And according to [this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJBuHm.png), the steps to create a chamfered polyhedron are as follows:

1. shrink the given polyhedron's faces by a factor $r, 0<r<1$
2. translate the shrunken faces outward [I'll call this distance $s$], so that their edges are coplanar with the
   original polyhedron's edges
3. construct the required hexagons from the original polyhedron's vertices and the vertices of the shrunk faces.

I haven't found any other explicit details regarding the relationship between $r$ and the shape of the hexagons, and so my questions are these (note that the value of $s$ will be directly dependent on the shape of the original face, and so $s$ will need to be represented with some parameter(s) that represent the face's shape somehow):

1. What is the general relationship between $r$ and $s$ in order to get coplanar vertices? Does this relationship change depending on how many times the polyhedron is chamfered?
2. What is the general relationship between $r$ and $s$ in order to get equilateral vertices? Does this relationship change depending on how many times the polyhedron is chamfered?
3. For equilateral and coplanar vertices, what value does $r$ need to be so that the diameter of the resulting hexagon equals the original side length? (ie. given pentagons that share edge $AB$, the resulting hexagon between the two would have a diameter equal to the length of $AB$ - shown in the images below) I assume this relationship could be obtained by setting up the answers to the previous questions as a system of equations

[image][image]

Note that this is different than my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3991193/748561) as it takes a different approach in constructing the chamfered faces - scaling along the relative Z axis vs. translating.

Comment: I have one of these made with Zometool. https://www.zometool.com/  You do get choices: the hexagons are all the same but are not regular. Reasonable choices (I) include making the area of the pentagon and a hexagon the same (II) making all edge lengths the same. You ought to draw a rhombus such as makes the rhombic triacontahedron: the diagonals are in proportion the golden ratio.Then you trim the two pointier vertices to make a hexagon with edges parallel in pairs. There is no choice in the angles.

Comment: @WillJagy If only computers could emulate full real-world physics in real time! Making a virtual Zometool would really help in visualizing all this

Comment: @IbrahimMahmoud: In your previous question, you wanted all the vertices to lie on a sphere. This doesn't happen in the equilateral Chamfered Dodecahedron; the vertices inherited from the dodecahedron lie on one sphere, and the vertices of the smaller pentagons are on a very-slightly-smaller sphere. Using [coordinates from David McCooey](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/ChamferedDodecahedron1.txt), if the edge-length is $1$, the radius of the larger sphere is $\frac1{20}\sqrt{3}(5+5\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{10(5+\sqrt{5})})\approx 2.87463$; the smaller, $\text{(complicated expression)}\approx2.86094$.

Comment: @WillJagy The Zometool one will not actually have equilateral hexagons; you have four yellow and two blue edges.

Comment: @MishaLavrov correct. The proportions of lengths of zometool `edges' are discussed somewhere, maybe links on their website. Within one color, the proportions are the golden ratio. Looking at my model here, the area of a hexagon is obviously larger than that of a pentagon, as, visually, a pentagon would fit entirely inside such a hexagon if separate models were made and placed on a tabletop. So, the hexagons would need to be a good deal narrower to get equal area. It appears from the comment by Blue that another choice is used, that of the vertices lying on a sphere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll consider the case of faces that are simultaneously equilateral and coplanar, leveraging the work done by David McCooey in generating [the coordinates of an equilateral chamfered dodecahedron (text link via dmccooey.com)](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/ChamferedDodecahedron1.txt) with unit-length edges.

McCooey gives the coordinates in terms of these values:
$$\begin{align}
c_0 &:= \tfrac14\left(1 + \sqrt{5}\right) \\
c_1 &:= \tfrac1{10}\sqrt{10\left(5 + \sqrt{5}\right)} \\
c_2 &:= \tfrac1{10}\left( 5 +              \sqrt{10\left(5 -\sqrt{5}\right)}\right) \\
c_3 &:= \tfrac1{20}\left( 5 + 5\sqrt{5} + 2\sqrt{10\left(5 +  \sqrt{5}\right)}\right) \\
c_4 &:= \tfrac1{10}\left( 5 +             2\sqrt{ 5\left(5 + 2\sqrt{5}\right)}\right) \\
c_5 &:= \tfrac1{20}\left(15 + 5\sqrt{5} + 2\sqrt{10\left(5 +  \sqrt{5}\right)}\right) \\
c_6 &:= \tfrac1{20}\left( 5 + 5\sqrt{5} + 4\sqrt{ 5\left(5 + 2\sqrt{5}\right)}\right) \\
c_7 &:= \tfrac1{20}\left(15 + 5\sqrt{5} + 4\sqrt{ 5\left(5 + 2\sqrt{5}\right)}\right) \\
\end{align} \tag{1}$$
Of the eighty vertices, we take two sets of five (where I'm assigning "$P$" and "$Q$" names to McCooey's "$V$"s):

$$\begin{align}
P_0 := V_{0} = (0, c_2, c_7)\quad
P_1 &:= V_{72} = (\phantom{-}c_3, c_3, c_3)\quad
P_2 := V_{8}  = (\phantom{-}c_2, c_7,  0)\\
P_3 &:= V_{10} = ( -c_2, c_7,  0)\quad
P_4 := V_{76} = ( -c_3, c_3, c_3) \\[4pt]
Q_0 := V_{60} = ( 0, c_4, c_5) \quad
Q_1 &:= V_{52} = (\phantom{-}c_0, c_6, c_3) \quad
Q_2 := V_{28} = (\phantom{-}\tfrac12, c_7, c_1) \\
Q_3 &:= V_{32} = (-\tfrac12, c_7, c_1) \quad
Q_4 := V_{56} = ( -c_0, c_6, c_3)
\end{align} \tag{2}$$
The $P$ vertices neighbor what would be a face of the dodecahedron in OP's images; such vertices lie on a sphere of approximate radius $2.87463$. The $Q$ vertices neighbor the corresponding pentagonal face of the chamfered dodecahedron; such vertices lie on a sphere of approximate radius $2.86094$. Define $P_\star := \frac15\sum P_i$ and $Q_\star:=\frac15\sum Q_i$, the centers of these faces.

OP's chamfering process scales a dodecahedral face by a factor of $r$ (taking $P_i$ to $P_\star+r(P_i-P_\star)$, then translates it by $z$. It's not clear if OP's "$z$" is a scalar or a vector, so I'll introduce a scalar $s$ and say that the translation is by the vector $(s-1)P_\star$. Then we have

$$Q_i = sP_\star + r (P_i - P_\star) \tag{3}$$

The scaling values are simply
$$\begin{align}
r &= \frac{|Q_0Q_1|}{|P_0P_1|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(c_2-c_3)^2 + c_3^2 +(c_3 -c_7)^2}} \approx 0.487457 \tag{4}\\[8pt]
s &= \frac{|Q_\star|}{|P_\star|} = \sqrt{
\frac{
(2c_1+2c_3+c_5)^2 + (c_4+2c_6+2c_7)^2 
}{(c_2+2c_3+2c_7)^2 + (2 c_3 + c_7)^2}} \approx 1.19577 \tag{5}
\end{align}$$

---

Of course, the above numerics are specific to the first iteration of the subdivision process OP is seeking to define in a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3991193/409). What to do after that isn't entirely clear, although it should be "obvious" that every iteration changes the geometry so that particular scale factors don't simply carry-over.

The first iteration is "easy" because all faces are equivalent, as are edges. At the second iteration, we have two types of faces (regular pentagons and non-regular hexagons) and two types of edges (bordering two hexagons, and bordering a hexagon and a pentagon). From there, the types of hexagons and the types of edges will only proliferate, adding complexity.

Consideration of strategies for later iterations would seem to go beyond the scope of this question, so I'll end my discussion here.

---

---

**Appendix.** Here's a bit more of a derivational approach that lends some insight into later chamfering iterations. In what follows, I'll be using $\lambda$ as the *scale factor* for edges, and $p$ (and also $q$) as the *distance* by which a scaled face is translated above its forebear.

**The equilaterality condition.**

Consider an edge $\overline{AB}$ of length $2m$, and let $C$ be on a neighboring face such that $C$ serves as the apex of isosceles $\triangle ABC$ with height $c$. Let $A_\lambda$ be the dilation of $A$ in $C$ by factor $\lambda$; likewise define $B_\lambda$. (Necessarily, $|A_\lambda B_\lambda| = \lambda|AB|=2\lambda m$.) Then, let $A_p$, $B_p$, $C$ be the translates of $A_\lambda$, $B_\lambda$, $C$ by distance $p$ perpendicular to the plane of $|\triangle ABC|$.

[image]

Equilaterality of the chamfer requires that $|A_pB_p|=|AA_p|=|BB_p|$. The second equality follows from $\triangle ABC$ being isosceles, so we need only consider the first. A couple of appeals to Pythagoras yields
$$4\lambda^2m^2 = p^2 + (1-\lambda)^2|AC|^2 = p^2 + (1-\lambda)^2 (c^2+m^2) \tag{A.1}$$
Repeating the argument for isosceles $\triangle ABD$ of height $d$ on the *other* neighboring face of $\overline{AB}$, with $q$ the corresponding translation distance, gives for the same scale factor $\lambda$
$$4\lambda^2m^2 = q^2 + (1-\lambda)^2 (d^2+m^2) \tag{A.2}$$

**The coplanarity condition.**

Viewing along $\overline{AB}$ (with midpoint $M$), the edge visually collapses to a point and the neighboring faces to segments $\overline{CM}$ and $\overline{DM}$ of lengths $c$ and $d$. Extending $\overline{CC_p}$ to meet the plane of $\square ABB_pC_p$ at $C'$ (and likewise obtaining $D'$), the dihedral angles between the chamfer plane(s) and the faces of the polyhedron become $\gamma := \angle CMC'$ and $\delta := \angle DMD'$.

[image]

Writing $\theta$ as the polyhedron's dihedral angle along $\overline{AB}$, we have a planar hexagon $AA_pB_pBB_qA_qA$ when $\gamma+\delta+\theta=180^\circ$. Consequently,
$$\begin{align}
\tan\theta = -\tan(\gamma+\delta) & = -\frac{\tan\gamma+\tan\delta}{1-\tan\gamma\tan\delta} \tag{A.3}\\[4pt]
&= -\frac{\dfrac{p}{(1-\lambda)c}+\dfrac{q}{(1-\lambda)d}}{1-\dfrac{pq}{(1-\lambda)^2cd}} \tag{A.4}
\end{align}$$
Thus,
$$(pq)-(1-\lambda)^2 c d) \tan\theta = (1-\lambda) (cq+dp) \tag{A.5}$$

**Equilaterality and coplanarity.**

Equations $(A.1)$, $(A.2)$, $(A.5)$ comprise a system of three equations in five unknowns: $\lambda$, $c$, $d$, $p$, $q$. In the specific case of chamfering the dodecahedron, we have $c=d=m\tan54^\circ$ and $p=q$, leaving just the unknowns $\lambda$ and $s$. Taking $m=1$, we can solve to obtain
$$\begin{align}
\lambda &= -5 - 2 \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{2 (25 + 11 \sqrt{5})} \approx 0.487457 \\
p &\approx 0.435995
\end{align} \tag{A.6}$$
Scale factor $\lambda$ here matches $r$ in $(4)$. Distance $p$ is consistent with $s$ in $(5)$ in that $(p+i)/i=s$, for the dodecahedral inradius $i= \frac{m}{10}\sqrt{250+110\sqrt{5}}\approx 2.22703$.

More generally, we don't have enough information to solve for unique values of our five parameters. But our equations only think *locally* along one edge of the polyhedron being chamfered. Every edge gives rise to a corresponding system; edges sharing a common face share the translation parameter (the analogue of $p$ and $q$); and, for universal equilaterality, the systems share the same scale factor $\lambda$. So, *globally*, we "should" obtain enough equations to determine unique parameters (or else find that no parameters can do everything we ask of them).

Those considerations are beyond the scope of this discussion, but I will note that we (and by "we", I mean "Mathematica") can eliminate $c$ and $d$ from the single-edge system to get a relation between the common scale factor $\lambda$ and the translation distances $p$ and $q$ for neighboring faces.

$$(1 + \lambda) (3\lambda-1) m^2 \sin^2\theta = p^2 + q^2 \mp 2 p q \cos\theta \tag{A.7}$$
(where I *suspect* "$\pm$" is always "$-$" (it is for the regular dodecahedron) but haven't verified this). Interestingly, this is exactly a Law of Cosines statement identifying $p$, $q$, and $m\sin\theta\sqrt{(1+\lambda)(3\lambda-1)}$ as sides of a triangle, with $p$ and $q$ surrounding angle $\theta$ (or its supplement). This suggests there might be a clean geometric argument behind all of this. (It also shows that we must have $\lambda \geq 1/3$.) Substituting back into the system, we find

$$
c = \frac{|p\cos\theta\mp q|}{(1-\lambda)\sin\theta} \qquad
d = \frac{|p\mp q\cos\theta|}{(1-\lambda)\sin\theta} \tag{A.8}
$$

That's enough typing for now.

Comment: Thank you for your work here and the reference to David McCooey's polyhedra site, these are certainly valuable resources! However, unless I'm misunderstanding, you've obtained the values of $r$ and $s$ using the precomputed $Q$ vertices, which I don't have access to - in fact, those are the vertices I hope to identify *using* $r$ and $s$. This is why I need the relationship between $r$ and $s$ (ideally $r$ as input and $s$ as output) so the chamfered faces can be procedurally generated, as well as how to get $r$ if I specifically want equilateral and coplanar faces.

Comment: @IbrahimMahmoud: *'However, unless I'm misunderstanding, you've obtained the values of $r$ and $s$ using the precomputed $Q$ vertices"* ... Correct. But, because all regular dodecahedra are similar, and because $r$ and $s$ are scaling factors, once they've been calculated in one instance, you can apply them to any regular dodecahedron you have on hand. ... There's no need for a "relation" here, since there's exactly one pair of values $r$ and $s$ that yields an equilateral-and-coplanar chamfering of the regular dodecahedron.

Comment: I suppose - and I can certainly use these values for my project; this process was definitely helpful - but this only works for one chamfering iteration, and so if I wanted to chamfer it a second or third time these values would not work given that I don't have their $Q$ vertices to work with (which you did state in your answer).

Answer (score 3):

***tl;dr*** If $y$ represents the side length of a face, $b$ the distance between a face's center and $y$'s midpoint, $l$ the distance between the face's center and a vertex on $y$, and $\theta_0$ the angle between the face and the adjacent face across $y$, then the expressions for $r$ and $s$ to get equilateral (only for the first two chamfers) and coplanar faces are:

$ \begin{align} \theta=\frac {180-\theta_0}{2},\quad u&=b\,tan(\theta),\quad y=2\,\sqrt {l^2-b^2} \\ r&=1-\frac {y}{\sqrt {l^2+u^2} + y} \\ s&=\frac {u\,y}{\sqrt {l^2+u^2} + y} \end{align} \tag {0}$

So I managed to figure out the answer to each of the questions - what was hindering my progress was trying to figure it all out without the second image below. Once I figured that out, everything else just fell into place! The following image shows all the variables used (note that $\theta_0$ is slightly misleading this this image: the second image below is more accurate):

[image]

## 1. Relationship between $r$ and $s$ so that the vertices are coplanar

In order for the vertices to be coplanar, they all need to be on the same plane that connects the two new pentagons together, which is shown in the first image below. This was the main thing that stumped me, as I didn't know how to easily represent "coplanar vertices" without a whole lot of unknowns with vectors. This drastically simplified the workflow, and the relationship between $s$ and $r$ was quickly found (note that $\theta_0$ is the angle between the two original faces, and half of the remaining angle - $180-\theta_0$ - gets divided between them, which is why $\theta=\frac {180-\theta_0}{2}$):

[image]
[image]

$ \begin{align} \theta&=\frac {180-\theta_0}{2} \\ c&=\frac{s}{tan(\theta)} \\ r&=1-\frac{c}{b} \\ r&=1-\frac{s}{b\,tan(\theta)} \\ s&=(1-r)\,b\,tan(\theta) \end{align} \tag {1}$

## 2. Relationship between $r$ and $s$ so that the vertices are equilateral

This is was notably more challenging than the previous solution, and it even tricked me into thinking I had solved it a couple times - but to make things easier, I conjured up $y$ to represent the side length of the original face (not shown in the images unfortunately: this is the line perpendicular to $b$). The solution for $s$ isn't that bad, but getting $r$ was certainly not as pretty as the one before (note that only two variables from $b$, $l$, and $y$ are required, as they are connected by the expression $l=\sqrt {b^2+\frac {y^2}{4}}$)...

[image]

$ \begin{align} r&=1-\frac {d}{l} \\ d&=\sqrt {x^2-s^2} \\ r&=1-\frac {\sqrt {x^2-s^2}}{l} \\ x&=r\,y \\ r&=1-\frac {\sqrt {r^2\,y^2-s^2}}{l} \\ s&=\sqrt {r^2\,y^2 - l^2\,(1-r)^2} \\ 0&=r^2\,(y^2-l^2)+r\,(2\,l^2)+(-l^2-s^2) \\ r&=\frac {-l^2+\sqrt {l^4-(y^2-l^2)(-l^2-s^2)}}{y^2-l^2} \end{align} \tag {2.1}$

Alternatively, if we replace $r$ with $1-\frac {c}{b}=1-\frac {s}{b\,tan(\theta)}$ (instead of just leaving it in and then solving for a quadratic later), a less complex solution can be found for $r$:

$ \begin{align} r&=1-\frac {s}{b\,tan(\theta)} \\ r&=1-\frac {\sqrt {r^2\,y^2-s^2}}{l} \\ r&=1-\frac {\sqrt {y^2\,(1-\frac {s}{b\,tan(\theta)})^2-s^2}}{l} \end{align} \tag {2.2}$

## 3. Relationship between $r$ and $s$ so that the vertices are coplanar and equilateral

Given that I need both coplanar and equilateral faces here, I simply used a system of equations using both the previous solutions and solved for $r$ and $s$ independently. There was a lot of simplifying done and the process was not pretty in the least, so for this answer I just laid out the groundwork and then skipped to the solution - let me know if you wish to see the entire process, or even if you find an easier/better way to do this! For the sake of clarity, I replaced all instances of $b\,tan(\theta)$ with $u$:

Solving for r (using the upper root):

$ \begin{align} s&=(1-r)\,u \\ s&=\sqrt {r^2\,y^2-l^2\,(1-r)^2} \\ (1-r)\,u&=\sqrt {r^2\,y^2-l^2\,(1-r)^2} \\ (1-r)^2\,u^2&=r^2\,y^2-l^2\,(1-r)^2 \\ &... \\ r&=\frac {-(l^2+u^2)+\sqrt {(l^2+u^2)^2-(y^2-l^2-u^2)\,(-l^2-u^2)}}{y^2-l^2-u^2} \end{align} \tag {3.1}$

Solving for s (using the lower root):

$ \begin{align} r&=1-\frac{s}{u} \\ r&=1-\frac {\sqrt {y^2\,(1-\frac {s}{u})^2-s^2}}{l} \\ 1-\frac{s}{u}&=1-\frac {\sqrt {y^2\,(1-\frac {s}{u})^2-s^2}}{l} \\ \frac{s^2}{u^2}&=\frac {y^2\,(1-\frac {s}{u})^2-s^2}{l^2} \\ &... \\ s&=\frac {u\,y^2-\sqrt {u^2\,y^4-(y^2-l^2-u^2)\,(u^2\,y^2)}}{y^2-l^2-u^2} \end{align} \tag {3.2}$

Thanks to WolframAlpha, a much simpler solution could be produced if all the values are assumed to be positive (given that we will never have negative distance or angles, this is a valid assumption):

$ \begin{align} s&=\frac {u\,y}{\sqrt {l^2+u^2} + y},\;u=b\,tan(\theta),\;y=2\,\sqrt {l^2-b^2} \end{align} \tag {3.3}$

And given that $r=1-\frac {s}{u}$, this gives us a nice solution for $r$ as well:

$ \begin{align} r&=1-\frac {y}{\sqrt {l^2+u^2} + y},\;u=b\,tan(\theta),\;y=2\,\sqrt {l^2-b^2} \end{align} \tag {3.4}$

---

In applying this to my dodecahedron (the magnitude of each vertex being $1$), I can now show that the solutions I discovered are correct (credit for the values for $r$ and $s$ goes to Blue's answer - note that these values are all approximations, rounded to the fourth digit-place):

Given: $b=0.4911,\quad l=0.6071,\quad y=0.7136,\quad \theta=\frac {180-116.5650}{2}=31.7175,\quad u=b\,tan(\theta)=0.3035$

Unknown: $r=0.4875,\quad s=0.1556$

**1. Relationship between $r$ and $s$ so that the vertices are coplanar**

$ \begin{align} r&=1-\frac{s}{b\,tan(\theta)}&=1-\frac{0.1556}{0.4911\,tan(31.7175)}&=.4873 \\ s&=(1-r)\,b\,tan(\theta)&=(1-0.4875)\,0.4911\,tan(31.7175)&=.1556 \end{align}$

**2. Relationship between $r$ and $s$ so that the vertices are equilateral**

$ \begin{align} r&=1-\frac {\sqrt {y^2\,(1-\frac {s}{b\,tan(\theta)})^2-s^2}}{l} &=1-\frac {\sqrt {0.7136^2\,(1-\frac {0.1556}{0.4911\,tan(31.7175)})^2-0.1556^2}}{0.6071}&=.4877 \\ s&=\sqrt {r^2\,y^2 - l^2\,(1-r)^2}&=\sqrt {0.4875^2\,0.7136^2 - 0.6071^2\,(1-0.4875)^2}&=.1556 \end{align}$

**3. Relationship between $r$ and $s$ so that the vertices are coplanar and equilateral**

$ \begin{align} r&=1-\frac {y}{\sqrt {l^2+u^2} + y}&=1-\frac {0.7136}{\sqrt {0.6071^2+0.3035^2} + 0.7136}&=.4875 \\ s&=\frac {u\,y}{\sqrt {l^2+u^2} + y}&=\frac {(0.3035)\,(0.7136)}{\sqrt {0.6071^2+0.3035^2} + 0.7136}&=.1555 \end{align}$

---

## Update

These equations may work for future subdivisions/chamfering as well, however faces will not continue to be equilateral (while still being coplanar). This is to be expected, however an issue arises of how to uniformly scale and translate the vertices of a face if it is *not* equilateral (given that $b$, $l$, and $y$ may vary per vertex). As such, my chamfering process would need to be updated so that it works with such faces.